# Where can I find .NET v1.0.5000.0?

Tags: .net-1.0

I've just been informed at my workplace that we have an application that is used in production that has stopped working. I'm searching as best I can to find where the source for the application is in our source control but without much luck. I'm really hoping that this isn't an application that was developed on a local machine and never checked into source control.

It seems that this application is very old and the original developer is long gone. In an attempt to find out more about this application I've used the .NET Reflector to have a look inside...and I've found that it references mscorlib, System, System.Data, System.Drawing, and System.Windows.Forms but all of them state that they are version 1.0.5000.0.

How is this possible? Could it be that this is an application that was developed against the .NET 1.0 framework and has lived in production ever since? Is it possible that if .NET 1.0 were installed on the machine that it might run or is .NET 3.5 backwards compatible.

Finding .NET v1.0.5000.0 will be a minor thing if I can find the source code for the app...but if not, I may need to figure out how to get this app running in our current environment...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like .NET 1.0 is indeed on your production box... pretty sure you can run as many versions of .NET as you want installed in parallel.

Samuel has already pointed out the download location for .NET 1.0, but one other thing that may help, if you can't find the source, is the [File Disassembler](http://www.denisbauer.com/NETTools/FileDisassembler.aspx) plugin for .NET Reflector. Then you can disassemble the whole thing in one hit & get what should be working source code (albeit with ugly private variable names).

Good luck...

Comment: Thanks for the link to the File Disassembler....should be useful if worse comes to worse and I have to get the source control from the assembly. I've already tried it out and its in a reasonably workable format...

Answer (score 6):

[This is the download for 1.0a](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=D7158DEE-A83F-4E21-B05A-009D06457787&displaylang=en). The production server will have 1.0 installed otherwise the application wouldn't run. And if it is an ASP application, IIS is configured to have it run in its own 1.0 app pool.

Answer (score 1):

Can you extract out the source code from reflector and see if that can be made compilable? Disclaimer: I expect this suggestion is fully as kooky as it sounds.

Comment: Looks like I can using the file Disassembler plugin suggested by Alconja